# What is wrong with my solution for code check problem CIELAB

Tags: c++

I am doing a code chef practice prblem https://www.codechef.com/problems/CIELAB in easy category. But my solution is not working. The submit screen is showing : Status wrong Answer

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int input ();
int difference (int, int);
int calculateWrongAns (int);

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    num1 = input();
    num2 = input();

    int actualAns = difference(num1, num2);
    int res = calculateWrongAns(actualAns);
    cout << res;
    return 0;
}

int input () {
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    return x;
}

int difference (int x, int y) {
    if (x > y) {
        return x - y;
    } else if (x < y) {
        return y - x;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int calculateWrongAns (int actualAns) {
    int lastNumber = actualAns % 10;
    int otherNumbers = actualAns / 10;
    int res;
    if (otherNumbers != 0) {
        res = (otherNumbers * 10) + (lastNumber == 1 ? 2 : lastNumber -     1);
    } else {
        res = lastNumber == 1 ? 2 : lastNumber - 1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the input and desired output? What should your program do?

Comment: Hi This problem is resolved. The answer provide by @ThomasSablik is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
res = lastNumber == 1 ? 2 : lastNumber - 1;
```

is wrong. You are splitting the result in last digit and other digits. If the last digit is 1, you are changing it to 2. If it not 1, you are subtracting 1. That means, if the result is 30, you are subtracting 1. The new result is 29. Two digits differ. That's not correct. You could use

```
int calculateWrongAns (int actualAns) {
    return (actualAns % 10) == 0 ? actualAns + 1 : actualAns - 1;
}
```